# Where did my bones go?

Tags: interface, bones

I know they're still there, I can see them in the object hierarchy window, I can add and remove vertices to their component groups, but I cannot get them to display in the viewport. What did I do to cause this?

Blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuvf2lpxyv5veq9/HK_HollowKnight.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've selected your object and toggled to local view, which only allows to see the selected object: Header menu > *View > Local View > Toggle Local View* (or numpad <kbd>/</kbd>)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

You messed up something with the workspace. I couldn't find out what, because in the menu the bones are checked in, but after I added a new Layout workspace I could see every bones. 
[image]